# Relation between smallest extent of spectrum and spectral radius of $T^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $\rho(T)=\lim_{n->\infty}||T^n||^{1/n}$, with $T$ being an element of a Banach algebra. Then we know that the largest extent of the spectrum of $T$ (spectral radius) is
$$\max\{|\lambda|:\lambda \in \sigma(T)\}=\rho(T)$$

[image]

By smallest extent I'm thinking of $\min\{|\lambda|:\lambda \in \sigma(T)\}$, but I'm not sure...

Because, when I use that notion, then we get

\begin{align}
\min\{|\lambda|:\lambda \in \sigma(T)\}=&\max\{|1/\lambda|:\lambda \in \sigma(T)\}\\
=&\max\{|\lambda|:\lambda \in \sigma(T^{-1})\}\\
=&\rho(T^{-1})
\end{align}

I don't get $\rho(T^{-1})^{-1}$

Comment: Your first equation is flawed. You have to take the RHS to the $-1$.

Comment: @amsmath Of course!!!! =D Many thanks ;)